# JPQL - Get most frequent item in collection

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jpql

## Problem

I'm trying to get the most frequent item in a collection that belongs to a table. So for instance, if I have Table 'Library' and Table 'Book' and 'Library' has a collection of 'Book's, I would like to retrieve ALL books from ALL Libraries. From this result, I would like the most frequent book. The problem is I need this is one query, if possible. It would also be ok if I just got a list of ALL the books but sorted by occurrence.

## What I've Tried

`SELECT l.books, COUNT(l.books) AS occur FROM Library l`

`SELECT b FROM Library l, l.books b ORDER BY b.name`

The second one sadly does not order by ALL books, it sorts each collection on its own.

If more information is need I can provide it of course.

I hope somebody can help me :(

Comment: if you want the most frequent book from all book can't you just select from book table? why select from Library? maybe i'm not getting your requirment

Answer (score 0):

Your first query is pretty close.  The ANSI standard version of the query is:

```
SELECT l.books, COUNT(l.books) AS occur
FROM Library l
ORDER BY occur DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Some databases use `TOP` or `LIMIT` to fetch only one row.

Comment: please take attention the OP wants the answer for JPQL, not SQL

Comment: "The state field path 'g.categories' cannot be resolved to a collection type", where g is my library, and categories is my books.